# Kerberos: kinit on Windows 8.1 leads to empty ticket cache

Tags: windows-authentication, kerberos, klist

I installed `Kerberos for Windows` on a new set-up Windows 8.1 machine.

- Domain: not set
- Workgroup: WORKGROUP

I edited the `krb5.ini` file in `C:\ProgramData\MIT\Kerberos5` directory like this:

```
[libdefaults]
  default_realm = HSHADOOPCLUSTER.DE

[realms]
  HSHADOOPCLUSTER.DE = {
    admin_server = had-job.server.de
    kdc = had-job.server.de
  }
```

After a restart, I made a `kinit -kt daniel.keytab daniel` to authenticate me against the Realm via console. Also getting a ticket by user and password via the `Kerberos Ticket Manager` seems to work fine, as the ticket is shown in the UI.

What I'm wondering about is, that when I call a `klist` I get an empty list back, which says something like `cached tickets: 0`:

[image]

This seems not normal to me, as my Ubuntu computer shows valid tickets by `klist` after a `kinit`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some more configuration to do? Sometimes I read about a `ksetup` tool, but I don't know which settings here are neccessary and which not...

============================================================

After I set

```
[libdefaults] 
  ... 
  default_ccache_name = FILE:C:/ProgramData/Kerberos/krb5cc_%{uid}
```

in my `krb5.conf`, the `kinit` command via console and via Kerberos Ticket Manager creates a file in the specified path. So far everything looks good.

But: The `kinit` command creates tickets with very different file names (long vs. short), depending if I run the console as "admin" (short name) or not (long name), see the screenshot below. The Kerberos Ticket Manager only shows one of the tickets:

- If run as admin:

  - Shows the ticket I created via admin console
  - Creates ticket files with short file names
- If run as normal:

  - Shows the ticket I created via "normal" console
  - Creates ticket files with long file names

[image]

The `klist` command still doesn't show the cached tickets, independent if console was opened as admin or not.

Comment: You have several open questions in this forum; I have asked for clarification on a few of them and you haven't responded to any of them. In this case, it ultimately becomes  a waste of a person's time trying to help you.  I am interested to help, but I am going to hold off responding to your questions further until you have responded to the earlier ones.

Comment: @D.Müller - do you've resolved your issue? (it might help me :) )

Comment: I'm just using the windows console and make a "kinit -kt C:\myuser.keytab myusername". Ticket cache still is shown as empty, but the ticket is created and I can authenticate (e.g. on my Kerberized Hadoop Cluster)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [MIT Kerberos documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.15/doc/basic/ccache_def.html) states that...

> There are several kinds of credentials cache supported in the MIT
> Kerberos library. Not all are supported on every platform ...
>
> - **FILE** caches are the simplest and most portable. A simple flat file format is used to store one credential after another. This is the
>   default...
> - **API** is only implemented on Windows. It communicates with a server process that holds the credentials in memory...
>    
>    The default
>   credential cache name is determined by ...
> - The `KRB5CCNAME`environment variable...
> - The `default_ccache_name` profile variable in *[libdefaults]*
> - The hardcoded default, `DEFCCNAME`

But AFAIK, on Windows the hard-coded default cache is **`API:`** and that's what you can manage with the UI. `kinit` also uses that protocol by default.

I personally never could use `klist` to use that protocol, even with the "standard" syntax i.e. either
  `klist -c API:`
or
  `set KRB5CCNAME=API:`
  `klist`

On the other hand, if you point `KRB5CCNAME` to a `FILE:*****` then you can `kinit` then `klist` the ticket; but it will not show in the UI and will not be available to web browsers and the like.

---

If `klist` command doesn't show the keys even after setting environment variable like `KRB5CCNAME` (i.e. `set KRB5CCNAME=C:\kerberos_cache\cache\krb5cache`, its a file not a directory. You'll have to create parent directory manually), then chances are that the `klist` command that you're running is not from MIT Kerberos Windows installation in `C:\Program Files\MIT\Kerberos\bin` but rather the `klist` command from Windows itself in `C:\Windows\system32`.

You can check that out by running `which klist` if you have `cygwin` tools. In this case, simplest solution is to copy `klist.exe` into MIT Kerberos installation's `bin` directory as a new file i.e. `klist_mit.exe`. Cache entries should be shown if you run `klist_mit` command.

Comment: I just set the "default_ccache_name" to "FILE:C:/ProgramData/Kerberos/krb5cc_%{uid}" in my "krb5.conf" file. The "kinit" command now creates the ticket file in this directory. I'm still able to see the ticket in my UI, and "klist" still shows no cached tickets.

Comment: Strange behavior: If I open my Windows console as admin, and make a "kinit" the Kerberos Ticket Manager UI doesn't show the ticket. But if I run the console normally, the "kinit" creates a ticket that is shown in the UI. However, "klist" still doesn't work!

Comment: klist doesn't show the tickets, but they are valid, as I e.g. can open a Kerberos-secured Hadoop Web-UI after making a kinit in my Windows console.

Comment: @D.Müller -- My 2 cents: Windows ships with a custom `klist.exe` command that seems to be SSPI-specific, but no `kinit.exe`; if you installed MIT Kerberos then your `kinit` should generate GSSAPI tickets that are "invisible" to the Microsoft SSPI library (i.e. to `klist.exe` and Internet Explorer) but visible to Java, (and also Chrome & Firefox when properly configured)

Comment: This comment is the right answer. I encountered this issue on Windows 10 today. I will edit your answer to include it.