# Kerberos Authentication using Credentials Cache works via Eclipse, but not Command Line

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, kerberos

Description: I have built an application that fetches a HDFS(Hadoop Distributed File System) File from a Remote Cluster on which Kerberos Authentication is applied. I could executed HDFS.copyToLocalFile(path1, path2) from Eclipse and it worked fine. But when I export the project as a runnable jar and try to run it through command line, it throws the below error. Note: I've followed the steps mentioned @https://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/message/26939797/ and was successful in running the project from Eclipse. I've checked for additional files in Eclipse but couldn't find any. I have Kerberos V5 MIT installed along with Network Identity Manager (4.0 version)

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$1.run(Client.java:680)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.handleSaslConnectionFailure(Client.java:643)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:730)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2800(Client.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1521)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1438)
... 70 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.selectSaslClient(SaslRpcClient.java:172)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.SaslRpcClient.saslConnect(SaslRpcClient.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupSaslConnection(Client.java:553)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$1800(Client.java:368)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:722)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$2.run(Client.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:717)
... 73 more
```

Note: I've configured the eclipsed related parameters into a Configuration.xml and bundled it into the classpath.

```
<property>
    <name>java.security.auth.login.config</name>
    <value>./Configuration/login.conf</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>java.security.krb5.conf</name>
    <value>./Configuration/krb5.conf</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/

Comment: Under _"Low-level secrets"_ you have some tips about enabling the Kerberos debug traces i.e. `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` and `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` plus, if you are using the REST interface, `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true`

Comment: I will also add my personal touch: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` is real useful to understand the configuration issues.

Comment: If you are running your tests on Windows -- which is not 100% clear in your post -- then you may also benefit from some info on the subtleties of the Kerberos ticket cache e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763936/kerberos-kinit-on-windows-8-1-leads-to-empty-ticket-cache/41771570#41771570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the Kerberos authentication fails, because your `login.conf` and `krb5.conf` files can't be found on runtime when using the JAR.

I had a similar problem, when I tried to access a file in my `assets` folder from the JAR file. The point is, that the paths change somehow when exporting the package as JAR. Do you have an opportunity to check the file paths somehow in your code, e.g.

```
String resourceFile = YourClass.class.getResource("/krb5.conf").getFile();
// check if resourceFile is null!
```

If this `class.getResource(...)` command works on running via IDE, but won't in your JAR, the problem is the difference in the file location.

I think this post could help you: [How to get a path to a resource in a Java JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941754/how-to-get-a-path-to-a-resource-in-a-java-jar-file)