# Windows ODBC connection to Presto (Kerberized) service

Tags: odbc, powerbi, teradata, kerberos, simba

I have a linux server running Presto with Kerberos authentication enabled (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/server.html).

Everything is well configured on the server since I get authenticated and I can run queries from clients running on windows and linux (using the presto-cli https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/cli.html#presto-cli-execution). The problem appears when I try to establish an ODBC connection for PowerBI using the Teradata or Simba drivers, I receive the following error:

```
[Teradata][Presto] (2010) Authentication or authorization error occurred.
[Simba][Presto] (2010) Authentication or authorization error occurred.
```

I followed this guide to set up the client: https://www.simba.com/products/Hive/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/hi/kerberos.htm

I an using the same keytab used on the tests with the presto-cli and when I request a ticket I see it on the MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager pointing to the correct credential cache but I am not sure why the driver doesn't get authenticated, could someone point me to some ideas on how to solve this?

An interesting finding is that I am not able to list the cached ticket on the command prompt (using klist) as in this other question ([Kerberos: kinit on Windows 8.1 leads to empty ticket cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763936/kerberos-kinit-on-windows-8-1-leads-to-empty-ticket-cache)).

Comment: _"not able to list the cached ticket on the command prompt (using klist)"_ > which one? `klist` provided by Windows, that reads only from the Microsoft LSA cache ? `klist` provided by Java, that reads only from a Linux-style file ? Or sthg provided by MIT Kerberos for Windows ?

Comment: Hi, using the one provided by windows. The one provided by MIT Kerberos is able to list it, but I think the ODBC manager will use the one provided by windows.

Comment: Does your ODBC driver configuration gives you a choice of SSPI (Microsoft) and/or GSSAPI (Java, Linux) libraries for Kerberos?

Comment: No, it doesn't give me any option, I think the problem might be related with the way the driver look up for the ticket (my gut feeling is that probably the ODBC driver is not using the Kerberos store but probably the windows one)